# Caching constructor causing "Property '...' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

Tags: typescript, constructor

Every now and then in my projects, I create classes with constructors that cache the objects they create so that if the constructor is called with identical parameters multiple times, it returns the same instance each time instead of creating a new instance that would be identical to one already created.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class X {
    private static __cache: Record<string, X> = Object.create(null);

    readonly name: string; // The compilation error happens on this line.

    constructor(name: string) {
        const cached = X.__cache[name];
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return cached;
        }

        this.name = name;
        X.__cache[name] = this;
    }
}
```

This code worked just fine with TypeScript, until I moved to 2.7 and turned on the `strictPropertyInitialization` . Now I get an error on `readonly name: string;` saying

> Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

I have multiple classes with the pattern above in my projects so I need to come up with one or more general solutions to get rid of the error.

Two solutions I don't want:

1. Turn off `strictPropertyInitialization`. I find it too useful in general to turn it off. Turning it on showed some definitions that needed to be updated to better reflect how some of my classes work, or prompted improvements in initialization code.
2. Add a definite assignment assertion to `name` so that it is declared as `readonly name!: string;`. The exclamation point causes TypeScript to no longer check whether `name` is definitely assigned. This removes the error but it is also punching too big a hole in the compiler checks for my taste. For instance, if I use the assertion and I ever accidentally drop the assignment `this.name = name` in the code above, then TypeScript won't raise an error. I like to be notified early of mistakes.

I presented a minimal example above but in my applications I have classes with many more fields, or fields that are created from significantly expensive computations rather than just being assigned from constructor parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For cases where the object's fields are expensive to compute, the solution I've preferred so far is to mark the `constructor` as `private` (`protected` is perhaps indicated in some cases) and declare a factory function as a static member on the class. Like this:

```
class X2 {
    private static __cache: Record<string, X2> = Object.create(null);

    readonly name: string;

    private constructor(nameSource: string) {
        this.name = expensiveComputation(nameSource);
    }

    // We use this factory function to create new objects instead of
    // using `new X2` directly.
    static make(name: string): X2 {
        const cached = X2.__cache[name];
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return cached;
        }

        return X2.__cache[name] = new X2(name);
    }    
}
```

Because the constructor always sets all its fields, TypeScript no longer has an issue. This requires that the code using the class use the factory function to create new objects instead of using the constructor directly.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution I've used for cases where my constructor is only assigning its parameters to fields without performing any significant computation is to just flip the logic in the constructor to perform field assignment before checking whether there's an instance already created. The field assignments may be done needlessly if it turns out that an instance already exists, but that's not something I'm going to worry about until profiling shows that it is a real problem in a real application.

It looks like this:

```
class X {
    private static __cache: Record<string, X> = Object.create(null);

    readonly name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        // Set the fields first...
        this.name = name;

        // And then figure out whether we have an instance to return.
        const cached = X.__cache[name];
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return cached;
        }

        X.__cache[name] = this;
    }
}
```

Using parameter properties, it could even be reduced to:

```
class X {
    private static __cache: Record<string, X> = Object.create(null);

    // The parameter on the constructor also defines the property on 
    // instances of X.
    constructor(readonly name: string) {

        // And then figure out whether we have an instance to return.
        const cached = X.__cache[name];
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return cached;
        }

        X.__cache[name] = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[https://www.ryadel.com/en/ts2564-ts-property-has-no-initializer-typescript-error-fix-visual-studio-2017-vs2017](https://www.ryadel.com/en/ts2564-ts-property-has-no-initializer-typescript-error-fix-visual-studio-2017-vs2017/)

> If the issue is happening inside our own code, the best thing we can do is to fix that manually by adding the definite assignment assertion modifier like explained above: in most scenarios, a bunch of   !  placed in the right spots will be enough fix your project.